# Factorization of polynomials with r indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

If F is a field, the ring of polynomials over F in indeterminate x is a Euclidean domain. So, if p(x), q(x) are two non-zero polynomials over F, then there exist polynomials s(x), r(x) in F[x] such that p(x)= q(x)s(x)+r(x), in which r=0 or the degree of r, deg(r)< deg(q).

Is this property true anymore in the ring of polynomials over F in r indeterminates, so is it true in F[x1, x2, ..., xr], even though it is not a PID?

May you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extended division algorithm which allows to divide a polynomial $f$ into a sequence $F=(f_1,\ldots,f_s)$ of polynomials such that
$$f= h_1f_1+\cdots+h_sf_s +r$$
where $h_1,\ldots,h_s$ and $r$ (remainder) are polynomials and either $r=0$ or the leading term of $r$ is not divisible by any of the leading terms of $f_1.\ldots,f_s$.
Note that in order to define the leading term, one needs a term ordering on the monomials of the polynomial ring. This ordering must be global such that the algorithm terminates. Have a look into computational commutative algebra and Gröbner bases.

Comment: Thank you! In fact I have to prove that F[x1, x2, ..., xr]/(x1) is isomorphic to F[x2, x3, ..., xr]. I have taken in consider the map F[x1, x2, ..., xr] into F[x2, x3, ..., xr] such that f(x1, x2, ..., xr)=f(x2, x3, ..., xr) and I think to prove that the kernel of this map is (x1). So if p(x1, x2, ..., xr) is a polynomial in this kernel, can I write it: p(x1, x2, ..., xr)= x1* q(x1,x2,...xr)+r(x1,x2,..,xr), in which r = 0 or the degree of r is less then the degree of x1?